# Add listener to a List<TextEditingController>

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying add listeners to a List of dynamic length.  The listeners need to be added in initState but the list is populated in a builder that doesnt get built until after initState runs, so I'm adding listeners to an empty list.  The ListView.builder is in a FutureBuilder.   The list doesn't get built until after the API call is complete.   Is there any way this an be accomplished?  Here's the code below.

```
    List<bool> _isVisibleList = [];
    List<TextEditingController> _textControllersList = List();


    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        for (int i = 0; i < _textControllersList.length; i++)
            {
                _textControllersList[i].addListener(() {
                    if (_textControllersList[i].text.contains(reg))
                        setState(() => _isValidList[i] = true);
        
                    else
                        setState(() => _isValidList[i] = false);
            });
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By the way, the `List()` constructor is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried on to init the listener after layout is complete?!

```dart
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance
        .addPostFrameCallback((_) => yourFunction(context));
  }
```

Comment: The ListView.builder is in a FutureBuilder.   The list doesn't get built until after the API call is complete.  This seems to be too slow for the ```WidgetsBinding.instance```.

Comment: Maybe you should approach this from a different corner. If you look to the bloc documentation page, there are 2 examples for a todo list. They have single listener on the todo array and rebuild the page when a new/updated todo arrives. Even if you don't want to use bloc, I guess you could create a listener for the entire list and rebuild upon change

Comment: Forgive me, I'm a little slow.  I've found some bloc docs but no ToDo examples.  Do you still have that link?

Comment: I'll try, when I posted the link in another answer these days, my answer was deleted by admins (because one shall not link to the outside) https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirestoretodostutorial